# swift: extend array comparability

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4.2

In swift 4 arrays are automatically comparable - but they check each element sequentially. Does element 1 match element 1, element 2 match element 2, etc.? - which is probably good standard behaviour.

But I'd like to extend / change this behaviour for a certain type Interval, so it doesn't matter what the order is of the elements, as long as the contents of the two arrays match. i.e. if both the arrays are sorted and match (using the original behaviour) then that should trigger comparable.

The trouble is, by defining my new behaviour, I 'override' and lose the existing behaviour (which I'd like ideally to keep so I can test once both arrays are sorted) - and so I get a warning 'All paths through this function will call itself'. Any ideas how to solve please

```
extension Array where Element == Interval {
    static func == (lhs: [Interval], rhs: [Interval]) -> Bool {
        return lhs.sorted() == rhs.sorted()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make Interval conform to Hashable. Now you can coerce the arrays to Sets and compare for equality without order mattering.

Comment: The only problem with this is the uniqueness property of `Set` so if you care about number of elements it might not match. Instead, convert it to something like `NSCountedSet` and check for equality.

Comment: @ColGraff - you're right but in my case there shouldn't be any repeated values so I was thinking Set should work.

Comment: @matt - Interval is an enum with Int raw value, so should get Hashable for free. So I tried coercing changing last line of code to:  return Set(lhs) == Set(rhs) but that was still giving me the same warning, pointing to the second line with error 'All paths through  this function will call itself'.

Comment: @domc: *"Interval is an enum with Int raw value"*: That would be a useful information in your question. – *"return Set(lhs) == Set(rhs) but that was still giving me the same warning"*: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @MartinR. You're right on both counts. I should have included and just rebuilt and error gone. It didn't change like it normally does when I changed the code. So this solution works.